# dynamic Url.Content

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to build a website in C# using MVC3 with Razor. I have to build it with themes, but I have problems setting a dynamic content to Url.Content, like it follows:

```
     <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/THEME-NAME/images/logo.png")" alt="logo" />
```

and I would like to set the value of THEME-NAME from my code. Let's say from an Application object. Is it possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give the ViewBag a shot.

in your controller action I would put :

```
ViewBag.ThemeName = "SomeName";
```

in your view :

```
<img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/"+ViewBag.ThemeName+"/images/logo.png")" alt="logo" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Would something like the code show below work for you? did not test it but may lead you in the right direction.

```
var themName = somevalue
var urlValue = "~/Content/themes/" + @themeName + "/images/logo.png"
<img src="@Url.Content(@urlValue)" alt="logo" />
```