# MVC jQuery image src Url.Content quotes issue

Tags: jquery, image, url, model-view-controller

I have my JS file where I am dynamically changing image src.

This is my current code that I am trying :

```
    $("#prodFront").attr("src", '@Url.Content("~/Order_Images/Campaigns/"' 
    + campaignKey + '"/"' + id + '"/General/front.png"")');
```

My image is actually located at location :

```
Root folder/Order_Images/Campaigns/
765662bd-06ec-4925-8611-f147e232a124/1/General/front.png

$("#prodFront").attr("src",
'@Url.Content("~/Order_Images/Campaigns/
765662bd-06ec-4925-8611-f147e232a124/1/General/front.png")');
```

But my code always goes to location like

```
http://localhost:50209/BuyNow/Index/@Url.Content(%22~/Order_Images/
Campaigns/765662bd-06ec-4925-8611-f147e232a124/1/General/front.png%22)
```

I can view the image here :

```
http://localhost:50209/Order_Images/Campaigns/765662bd-06ec-4925-8611-  
f147e232a124/1/General/front.png
```

Comment: @halfer : whats your problem ?

Comment: Err, I don't have one. Thank you, though.

Answer (score 1):

As `campaignKey` and `id` are JavaScript variable. You can't use them with `@Url.Content` since it will be execute by Razor engine on server side.

As a workaround, you can generate the url using placeholder's `-1` and `-2` are used to generate URL, which is replaced using simple string manipulation.

```
//Generate URL
var url ='@Url.Content("~/Order_Images/Campaigns/-1/-2/General/front.png")';

//Replace placeholder
url = url.replace('-1', campaignKey).replace('-2', id);

//Set image
$("#prodFront").prop("src",url);
```

Comment: Hey @Satpal, just realized the second half of my response is pretty much using the same method that you're saying. Is there any reason one or the other should be used? Or does it come down to preference?

Answer (score 0):

`@Url.Content` is a razor command that uses C# to create a string when the page is called. You cannot pass in `@Url.Content` as a "dynamic" value, you would need to call `Url.Content` in your controller and have it pass the resulting string to your javascript. That's why it's coming up as `http://localhost:50209/BuyNow/Index/@Url.Content(%22~/Order_Images/`. 
Making an Ajax call to the server would be how I would handle it.

```
$.ajax({
        url: Url.Content("GetImageUrlAction", "SomeController" ),
        data: {id = theImageYouWantsId},
        success: function( returnData ){
                $('#prodFront').attr('src', returnData.imageUrl );
            }
    });
```

Then have a controller like this

```
public JsonResult GetImageUrlAction( string, campaginKey, string id ){
    var imageUrl = Url.Content( "~//Order_Images//Campagins//" + campaginKey + "//" + id + 
                                "//General/front.png" );
    return Json( new { imageUrl } );
}
```

If your base directory isn't going to be changing, you could set a base variable on page load and then just add the campaginKey and id to it later

```
//Declare your variable on document ready
$(document).ready( function(){
    baseUrl = '@Url.Content( "~/Order_Images/Campaigns/" )';
});
```

And then later in your jquery you can add to it

```
$("#prodFront").attr("src", baseUrl + campaginKey + "/" + id + 
"/1/General/front.png" );
```

Comment: But if we see this answer , we can have dynamic url

http://stackoverflow.com/a/8266453/5610512

Comment: @rohankoshti I think i misunderstood your question. Do you want an image that changes while on the page, or an image that changes (potentially) between pages?

Comment: the image would change with jquery function. I have twon images with their thumbnails .. and their are dynamic number of such sets .. no of images in one campaign = no of sets .. each set has front and back image of the product .. so on dropdowon change i need both images changed .. everything with jquery